Get SUMPRODUCT with multiple column and row criterias and ignore criteria if cell with criteria is empty




A
B
C
D
E
F
G




1


2024
2024
2024

2024


2


Q1
Q2
Q3

Q1


3
Brand A
Product 1
500
70
60

Brand A


4
Brand A
Product 2
100
47
300

Product 1


5
Brand A
Product 3
800
21
200
500



6
Brand B
Product 1
90
56
150




7
Brand C
Product 1
45
700
790




8
Brand C
Product 2
600
400
10




9










In cell G5 I extract the sum from the table based on multiple column and row criteria using this formula:  =SUMPRODUCT((A3:A8=G3)*(B3:B8=G4)*(C1:E1=G1)*(C2:E2=G2)*(C3:E8)).
This formula works without any issue.

However, now I want to implement that if one of the cells in Column G is empty this filter criteria should be ignored when summing up the values. 
For example if I leave the cell G4 empty the value should be 1400 because the criteria for Column B gets ignored and the sum is calculated based on the criteria for Column A, Row 1 and Row 2 which in the example is 500+100+800 = 1400.
I tried to go with this formula:
=SUMPRODUCT((A3:A8=G3)*IF(G4="";"*";(B3:B8=G4))*(C1:E1=G1)*(C2:E2=G2)*(C3:E8))

However, it returns #VALUE! error.
How do I need to modify the formula to make it work?

Did you try value 1 instead of "*"?

You can use this https://tabletomarkdown.com/convert-spreadsheet-to-markdown/ to convert an excel table to a markdown.

BlackCat is right (in my test case), what you're basically doing is multiplying TRUE(1) with FALSE(0), so in your second attempt, you replaced either 1 or 0 with a wildcard *, which doesn't work. You can test this by selecting parts of your formula and press F9 (newer versions even show it in a textbox).

As already mentioned in the comments. The solution is to use 1 instead of "*".
=SUMPRODUCT((A3:A8=G3)*IF(G4="";1;(B3:B8=G4))*(C1:E1=G1)*(C2:E2=G2)*(C3:E8))


Or SUMPRODUCT((A3:A8=G3)((G4="")+(B3:B8=G4))(C1:E1=G1)(C2:E2=G2)(C3:E8))
